# How to access to a nested components in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I get a Vue component like that:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>other things...</div>
    <FilterPopUp ref="filterPopUp">
      <FilterInput ref="filterInput"/>
    </FilterPopUp>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import FilterPopUp from './filter-popup.vue';
import FilterInput from './filter-input.vue';
export deafult {
  name: 'Filter',
  components: {
    FilterPopUp,
    FilterInput,
  },
  method: {
    resetOptionStore() {
      // this.$refs.filterInput.resetFilter();
      console.log(this.$refs.filterPopUp);
      console.log(this.$refs.filterInput);
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

What I want to do is get access to `FilterInput` Component in `resetOptionStore` method, but I failed.

The actual value of `this.$refs.filterInput` is `undefined`, how can I work out this problem?

[image]

Comment: Give a try to `this.$refs.filterPopUp.filterInput` like a regular query selector.

Comment: @kissu It doesn't work, but I have find out what was happend. I have used `v-if` attribute at `FilterPopUp` which causes this problem...XD,

Comment: Search your conscience if this is really a good idea! The parent-child relationship between  Vue components arises just from the "accident" of their positions in the DOM. The components should be interacting with your store, not with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should work, I just created a below working code snippet just for a demo. You can check and try to find the root cause by taking the reference.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['childmsg'],
  template: '<div>{{ childmsg }}<slot></slot></div>',
  methods: {
    call() {
        console.log('Child call');
    } 
  }
});

Vue.component('innerchild', {
  props: ['innerchildmsg'],
  template: '<li>{{ innerchildmsg }}</li>',
  methods: {
    call() {
        console.log('inner Child call');
    } 
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.childComponent.call());
    console.log(this.$refs.innerChildComponent.call());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child ref="childComponent" childmsg="This is a child message">
    <innerchild ref="innerChildComponent" innerchildmsg="This is a inner child message"></innerchild>
  </child>
</div>
```